# How to setup Apache HTTP server with the vulnerable OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache-http-server, heartbleed

I want to do some test, so I want to set up an [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) server ***with*** the vulnerable [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) (specifically with the [Heartbleed bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed)), and I'd better do it from source.

How do I do that?

Comment: Just use the vulnerable version, making sure to include the heartbeat extension.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is to use [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) or [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP). The inbuilt OpenSSL used there is vulnerable. You don't have to build from source, just to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Amazon [AMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image) image available online. Aside from that, just install the version of OpenSSL that [Heartbleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) is present in. I believe anything below "g" will suffice.

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (plus 1.0.2-beta) are the vulnerable versions.  Various flavors of OpenSSL 0.9.8 are still in circulation, and installing a "pre-g" edition of that won't give you a vulnerable server.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set up a vulnerable webserver for testing, then you do not need to bother with Apache. The `openssl` command already includes all batteries. It is available on (almost) all Linux distributions, Windows packages are probably included with any WAMP package.

The following three commands create a private key, append a self-signed certificate for `localhost` to it and finally start a HTTPS service that outputs some parameters when visited.

```
openssl genrsa -out server.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key server.pem -subj /CN=localhost >> server.pem
openssl s_server -www
```

In your browser (or test program), you can now use the URL `https://localhost:4433/`.